# Add progress bar to MySQL in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm using the below code to load data from a file to my database

```
mysql -h $_host -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db --local_infile=1 -e  "use $_db" -e" 


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$_file'
REPLACE INTO TABLE my_db.\`load_temp\`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY 0x2c
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'

(  
 \`supplier_Pin\`,
 \`products_sl\`,
 \`products_long_description\`,
 \`rv_no\`,
 \`weight\`,
 \`products_cost\`   
 )
   ; "
```

The files are around 500 MB so it does consume a lot of time.
I need to display the a progress bar during the import.
please suggest a method to do it

Comment: Did you try pv? Check it out http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/how-can-i-monitor-the-progress-of-an-import-of-a-large-sql-file

Comment: Update to MariaDB, login into a console and type **show processlist**. It has a build in progress indicator for several processes.

Comment: @mim. the first thing I tried was pv,but couldn't figure out its usage in this specific case nor could I find a proper demo.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I know but I don't have the permission to do that.

Comment: @RandomSeed I cant understand its usage in this case..show me a demo?

Comment: You are right I don't quite see how to involve `pv` in this task either. I suppose you will need to split your input file in smaller chunks and make your own progress bar :/